# How to install Excel 2003 add-on (*.xla)

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-excel, addons

I need to create something, bat scripts(?), to install an add-on for Excel 2003 so that the end user will not required to manually install add-on from Excel's manual Tool->Addin... then browse.

For example, my add-on is a file:

```
C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\myAddin.xla
```

Any suggestions or just steps from command console to install the add-on?

The client PC is Windows XP based PC.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the wonderful step by step explanation available on this [site](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/installing-an-add-in-in-excel-2007/)  or [here](http://209.85.229.132/search?q=cache:qtFAYhtV8NQJ:www.dslimited.biz/excel_tutorials/installadd-in.html+How+to+install+Excel+2003+add+in+xla&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&client=firefox-a).

But i would suggest that you can use automation is easy

From [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/280290)

- Add a new workbook.
- Call the Add method of the AddIns
  collection to add the new add-in to
  the list of add-ins in Excel Add-In
  Manager.
- Set the Install property of the AddIn
  object to True (equivalent to
  selecting the add-in the Add-in
  Manager).

  > Dim oXL As Object, oAddin As Object
  >   Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  >   oXL.Workbooks.Add
  >   Set oAddin = oXL.AddIns.Add("C:\test.xla", True)
  >   oAddin.Installed = True
  >   oXL.Quit
  >   Set oXL = Nothing

Note that a workbook is added prior to calling the Add method in this example. The Add-in Manager in Excel is not available unless there is at least one visible workbook open. Without this line of code, you receive one of the following error messages:

Comment: Nice link resources. Based on the information, I can copy the xla file to either folders (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OfficeXX\Library or C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\Microsoft\AddIns). Then addin is in the Addin list. However, how can I make this item checked in the list? Somewhere in reg or xml config file?