# How to make add-on visible on toolbar by script or batch process?

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-registry, addons

I have an add-on for Excel 2003. I tried to use MSDN's `.VBS` script to make it installed, see [my previous post question](https://superuser.com/questions/58879/how-to-install-excel-2003-addin-xla). It seems working as add-on, but it does not displayed on toolbar when it is first installed on a box.

What I have to do is to go to Tools->Add-Ins.. to un-check my add-on, for example myAddin, and then go back to the same dialog window again to check it.

I think there must be somewhere Excel has config settings in XML or registry? Any way to run a script to set this add-On visible in toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the reference to the addin?

You can add the reference during the Workbook_Open event in ThisWorkbook, or in Auto_Open.  Something along the lines of:

```
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile < full path to your xla >
```

If you have installed the xla & know the GUID, then you can use:

```
'change this to match the GUID generated by the uid generator tool
'the curly braces are not optional.
strGUID = "{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" 

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _ 
                                    GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0
```

Comment: I'll try the second method since I have xla installed. How can I  find out the GUID for the addin?